# Speed up reaction to TouchableWithoutFeedback

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I need to deal with a rapid clicks of a button; as fast as the user can click.

This will update a number at the top of the screen.

Code:

Rendered:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.clickClickBtn}>    
    <View style={styles.clickSummary}>
        <Text>Click</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Which calls:

```
clickClickBtn = () => {
    this.props.clickClickBtn(this.props.serviceId);
}
```

Which calls:

```
clickClickBtn = (id) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        saveData:{
            ...prevState.saveData,
            currentBalance: String(bigInt(this.state.saveData.currentBalance).add(this.getPerClick(id))),
        }
    }));
}
```

This is rather slow and laggy (still in expo though, is that the reason?). I was unsure as to whether this could be the setState taking a while as the total is rendered on the screen via a call of the current state.

I've tried to optimize my program to speed it up to no avail.

Any ideas of how to speed this up?

Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your code, I feel like slowness resides in `this.getPerClick(id)`.
everything else doesn't need to change.

FYI nothing is wrong with Expo.
also it's different in every case but sometimes it's better to keep local changes to state and then batch update them at once.